# Rails; sum total

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd love to refactor the code below in more like Ruby way.

```
def cal_total
    total = nil
    items.each do |item|
      total = total + item.itemable.amount
    end
    total
end
```

Basically just iterate object, fetch the each amount, and return the total.
Any idea?

**update**

`total = item.itemable.amount`  is correct.

Comment: What is itemable, it can be done with a single query as well

Comment: items have polymorphic relations to other models.

Comment: @TSH Add your associations.  `items.itemable` - does this work ?

Comment: @dp7 sorry I updated the question.

Comment: @TSH Added answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
items.map(&:amount).inject(0, &:+)
```

The exact syntax depends on your code.  Although not necessarily a Ruby Way, it's more concise and functional style.

Comment: Can be also written as `items.map(&:amount).reduce(&:+)` or in Rails `items.map(&:amount).sum`

Comment: `items.itemable.map(&:amount).inject(0, &:+)`

Comment: @user000001, that's true, `inject` and `reduce` are almost the same in ruby.

Comment: @Sid: they're __exactly__ the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, I am eager loading by using `includes` to avoid `n + 1` query problem

```
items = Item.includes(:itemable) 
total = items.map{ |item| item.itemable.amount }.sum
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is one more thing you can do while refactoring.

In Item model, you can delegate amount method to itemable

```
class Item
  delegate :amount, to: :itemable, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

Now you can get amount without `.` operator.

```
items.map{ |item| item.itemable_amount }.sum
```

With `prefix: false` you can write,

```
items.map{ |item| item.amount }.sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your association:

```
items.map(&:itemable).sum(&:amount)
```

OR

```
items.map { |i| i.itemable.amount }.sum
```

Comment: This doesn't work `NoMethodError: undefined method +'`

Comment: @RSB My first edit was `items.map(:itemable).collect(&:amount).sum` - then I thought why to use `map` or `collect` twice, better to put it inside a block. Then this came as an edit :)

Comment: @TSH there was a typo in my first answer due to which you had got `NoMethodError: undefined method +'` , try this `items.map(&:itemable).sum(&:amount)`

Comment: @Downvoter: Please let me know how can I improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `sum`

```
items.map{ |item| item.itemable.amount }.sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total sum this way, I think this is the best practice and the most efficient in matter of performance

```
items.map(:&itemable).pluck(:amount).reduce(:+)
```